# MySQL retrieval from database not retrieving multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve all data with the `LIKE` query from the users input and match it to the database, it works but only returns one record but I have many records in the table.

It returns the closest record it can find,

so say for example I have 2 records who's ItemDesc field contains the characters 'The', when I search for 'The' in my input box and click submit it returns the closest (earliest created) record when it is supposed to return both.

```
<?php
$username = "a3355896_guy";
$password = "++++++";
$hostname = "mysql5.000webhost.com";    
$dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to      MySQL");

mysql_select_db("a3355896_book") or die("Unable to connect to database");

$ItemDesc = $_POST['ItemDesc'];
$query = "select * from StockItems where ItemDesc LIKE '%$ItemDesc%'"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Sorry was supposed to included the retrieval:

```
<?php
if ($num>0)
{
echo "<center><table border=1><tr><th>Item Code</th><th>Item Desc</th>";
echo "<th>Item Stock Qty</th>";
echo "<th>Item Unit Price</th><th>Item Category</th></tr>";
$ItemCode = mysql_result($result,$i,"ItemCode");
$ItemDesc = mysql_result($result,$i,"ItemDesc");
$ItemStockQty = mysql_result($result,$i,"ItemStockQty");
$ItemUnitPrice = mysql_result($result,$i,"ItemUnitPrice");
$ItemCategory = mysql_result($result,$i,"ItemCategory");
echo "<tr><td>$ItemCode</td><td>$ItemDesc</td><td align=right>";
echo "$ItemStockQty</td>";
echo "<td align=right>$ItemUnitPrice</td>";
echo "<td>$ItemCategory</td></tr>";
echo "</table></center>";

}
else
{
echo "<form name='DeleteStock2'>";
echo "<p> Sorry, $ItemDesc does not exist!<p>";
echo "<input type='button' value='Leave' onclick='history.go(-1)'>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Give us some of the table data that you're searching from. It's hard to diagnose the issue if we don't know what you're searching against.

Comment: Where are you trying to retrieve data? You're just using `mysql_num_rows` to get the number of rows in your result.

Comment: Sorry have edited and shown the retrieval

Comment: You're in urgent need of some [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually accessing your data here- you need to iterate over the result set.

```
$setLength = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i = 0; $i < $setLength; $i++){
    //Here, mysql_fetch_assoc automatically grabs the next result row on each iteration
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    //do stuff with "row"
}
```

Unless you ARE doing that and you just chose to not include it in your snippit. Let us know :)

--Edit--
First off, I apologize- out of old habit I suggested that you use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of the mysqli set of functions.

Try using the fetch_assoc or fetch_array functions, it could solve your issue. I've never used the method you used, I think it has been deprecated for a while.
Check it out here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Yeah- you're using a deprecated function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php
I actually realized you should upgrade to the mysqli family of functionality anyways. I'm going to edit this answer

Comment: Not sure how I would change my current retrieval code to use fetch_assoc or fetch_array functions, have never quite used them before.

Comment: Thanks, all works with the iteration, need to check for deprecated functions in the future :d

Comment: @Ryman Holmes
Hard to do it sometimes too, but if it's something you're unfamiliar, I suggest ALWAYS consulting the documentation of the language you're using (MySQL, PHP, etc) and just at least checking from the source. A lot of the time you'll get answers from programmers with very little experience that seem good at first, but later perhaps don't pan out as well.
Happy coding!